# Changing Background color of a view inside a Fragment

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-fragments

Ok, this is my new problem;

I am trying to change the background color of a View inside a Fragment on touch Event.

It is already setup and working fine. But it seems the background just won't change of color.

I do suspect this happens because this view has also other views on it on fill parent So even if it changes color I won't be able to see it.

Anyhow I have already set up those views color to Color.TRANSPARENT but it still does not work...

Here is my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:id = "@+id/lay_1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/position"
    android:id="@+id/pos"/>


<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pos"
    android:id="@+id/flipper_1"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/cart"/>

    <include layout="@layout/ang"/>

    <include layout="@layout/data_graph"/>

</ViewFlipper>
```

If you need more information don't mind asking for it.

Thanks a lot.

Luis.

Comment: Is it the Relative Layout that you are trying to change? I think that in xml android is expecting 4 bytes for a colour, the first being the alpha. Which view has the touch event attached?

Comment: It is the relativelayout the one I want to change its color. The eventlistener is attached to the viewflipper.

Comment: In any case I have tried changing the.layout alpha and it works. But changing colors does not display any results...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and you should try to create a method called at the oncreate of the fragment to update the inside of the fragment view (background color, text...)
ex:
public static LinearLayout getcolor(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, boolean bf){

```
int i;
View v;
TextView t;
LinearLayout ll;

int r = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*255+1);
int g = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*255+1);
int b = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*255+1);

i=Color.argb(200,r,g,b);
if(bf){
    ll = (LinearLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front, container, false);
    v=ll.findViewById(R.id.frag_card_front);
    v.setBackgroundColor(i);
    t=(TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textf);
    t.setText(""+i);
}
else{
        ll = (LinearLayout )inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);
        v=ll.findViewById(R.id.frag_card_back);
        v.setBackgroundColor(i);
        t=(TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textb);
        t.setText(""+i);

}

return ll;

}


public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout ) getcolor(inflater, container,true);
     return ll;
    }
}


public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout ) getcolor(inflater, container,false);      
        return ll;
    }
}
```